# Wait for an operation to finish using CLI

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I have CodeBuild running "aws apprunner start-deployment" but I don't want code build to finish until the deployment is done. In the [docs](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/apprunner/start-deployment.html), it says ...

> This is an asynchronous operation. On a successful call, you can use the returned OperationId and the ListOperations call to track the operation’s progress.

but I'm not sure exactly how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the output to a variable. Then use the `list-operations` operation to see if it's still running.

```
id=$(aws apprunner start-deployment)
while aws apprunner list-operations | grep -q "$id"; do
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks!